# Can I get Jetty to rewrite Cookie paths?

Tags: java, mod-rewrite, cookies, jetty, embedded-jetty

We've got a lot of applications based on Jetty. For historical reasons; these have been sitting behind Apache servers. One of the duties of Apache has been rewrites, and we want to move to using just Jetty. But we are hitting some snags when it comes to porting it. Specifically Cookie path rewrites. Is it even possible in Jetty?

The original config for Apache looks like this:

```
ProxyPassMatch          ^/${basePattern}/${market}/(${appContextName}/.*)                http://127.0.0.1:8080/app/${symbol_dollar}1 retry=0
ProxyPassReverse        /                                                             http://127.0.0.1:8080/

ProxyPassInterpolateEnv on
ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /appCookiePath /${basePattern}/${market}/${appContextName} interpolate
```

I've looked at the code for both Rule (from the rewrite API) as well as Jetty Handlers. I can't really find anything in those APIs that would let me rewrite the Cookies... Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in feature of Jetty for rewriting `Set-Cookie` headers or `Cookie` headers.

If you are not afraid of Java code, you could create a `CookiePathHandler` that is placed at the start of the Server handler list to perform this logic for you in java code.

Pop into jetty-users mailing list or #jetty on chat.freenode.net for help (if you've never written a Jetty handler before)

Comment: I've looked into writing a custom handler, but from the available API (mainly the Servlet API) I really can't find a way to rewrite the Cookies. I could maybe duplicate all Cookies under one path to another, but no proper way of manipulating them.